# Calculate the time difference in hours in vertical colums in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

How do I calculate the time difference in hours between the date and time if the date/ hour data is vertically in columns?

**EDIT: The difference needed is between the days and hours e.g.
diff between 18/01/2018 22.50.13 and 22/01/2018 17.35.06 will be 91hours roughly**

See image for more details:

[image: example data picture]

Comment: Difference between what? That row and the row above? That row and the row at the top? Bottom?

Comment: @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose edited as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel stores dates as whole numbers (the number of days since Jan 1, 1900) and times as the decimal fraction of a day.  You can see this by formatting the dates and times as numbers.

If you add the date and time together, you get a single number representing the date and time.  Subtracting those will give the number of days between the two datetimes, and multiplying by 24 gives the number of hours.

This formula:

`=24*((A2+B2)-(A3+B3))`

will give the result you're looking for.

[image]

Column C is formatted as numbers.

If you find this answer helpful, please click the checkmark near the top to accept the answer and remove it from the unanswered queue.  Thanks and best of luck.

Comment: Perfect - just what I needed!